# SwiftUI TapGesture Not Working with NavigationLink in List on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

When I use `.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{ //code to run })` on a `NavigationLink` in SwiftUI for iOS, the code runs fine and the link opens.

However, if the `NavigationLink` is in a `List`, the code runs but the link does not open.

Is there another way I can run some code *after* the `List` `NavigationLink` is tapped, but *before* the `TextEditor` appears?

Using `.onAppear` on the `TextEditor`, is not suitable because I need the code to run before the TextEditor appears - partly due to a bug with `TextEditor`'s re-rendering and partly to keep things flowing in the right order.

Code to replicate the issue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textString = ""
    @State private var listMembers = ["Link A", "Link B", "Link C"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(listMembers, id: \.self) { member in
                    NavigationLink(member, destination: TextEditor(text: $textString))
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            textString = "Link A, B, or C was tapped."
                            print(textString)
                    })
                }
                NavigationLink("Link D", destination: TextEditor(text: $textString))
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        textString = "Link D was tapped."
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with is using ForEach instead of List. It requires more formatting to make it look nice, but it seems to solve the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textString = ""
    @State private var listMembers = ["Link A", "Link B", "Link C"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                /*List(listMembers, id: \.self) { member in
                    NavigationLink(member, destination: TextEditor(text: $textString))
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            textString = "Link A, B, or C was tapped."
                            print(textString)
                    })
                }*/
                ForEach(listMembers, id: \.self) { member in
                    NavigationLink(member, destination: TextEditor(text: $textString))
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            textString = "Link A, B, or C was tapped."
                            print(textString)
                    })
                }
                NavigationLink("Link D", destination: TextEditor(text: $textString))
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        textString = "Link D was tapped."
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```